# Oracle association operator with types and table with index

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

Does Oracle 12C R2 (12.2.0.1) not support the association operator **=>** when calling a type constructor with a query on a table with an index? or is there another way to call a constructor and explicitly assign values to attributes?

Please note, this worked in 11G and 12C R1

ie.
if I have a custom type like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE T_MY_TYPE FORCE AS OBJECT (
  id     NUMBER(10, 0),
  attribute1 VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
  attribute2 VARCHAR2(2 BYTE),
  attribute3 VARCHAR2(3 BYTE),
  CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION T_MY_TYPE RETURN SELF AS RESULT );
```

And a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  idd  NUMBER(10, 0),
  att1 VARCHAR2(60 BYTE),
  att2 NUMBER(4),
  att3 NUMBER(8),
  att4 NUMBER(5)
);

INSERT ALL
INTO my_table (idd, att1, att2, att3, att4) VALUES (1, '123', 3, 4, 4)
INTO my_table (idd, att1, att2, att3, att4) VALUES (2, '123', 7, 4, 4)
INTO my_table (idd, att1, att2, att3, att4) VALUES (3, '234', 5, 4, 4)
  SELECT *
  FROM dual;
```

And I try to query it with:

```
SELECT t_my_type(attribute1 => NULL,
                 id => NULL,
                 attribute2 => NULL,
                 attribute3 => NULL)
FROM my_table mt
WHERE mt.att3 = 1
      OR mt.att3 > 3;
```

It works, but as soon as I add an index on attr3 with the below command:

```
CREATE INDEX myIndex ON my_table (att3);
```

It fails with ORA-06553: PLS-306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'T_MY_TYPE'

Please note the type constructor without the association operator has no issues, see:

```
SELECT t_my_type(NULL,
                 NULL,
                 NULL,
                 NULL)
FROM my_table mt
WHERE mt.att3 = 1
      OR mt.att3 > 3;
```

Comment: This look like a possible bug, can you please report this to Oracle Support?

Comment: @learningloop I have reported it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The support request was registered as a bug, see [Bug 27653957 : TYPE CONSTRUCTOR FUNCTION FAILS WITH ORA 6553 PLS-306 WITH INDEX](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/BugDisplay?id=27653957)

Until it gets resolved, the workaround (as mentioned in the Oracle Bug) is to remove the constructor.  This can be a bit of a pain if you have empty initializations (ie. `v_variable := t_my_type()`)
throughout your code, as you will need to replace these with NULLs 
(ie. `v_variable := t_my_type(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)`)